# How to read protected PIC16F676

Tags: pic, microchip, pic16f, tl866

[image]

Well I have broken pcb and it has a PIC16f676 on it. PCB Not working very well. I want to replace it with new pic16f676 but I cant read data from on board PIC. it ruturns "0000" in everywhere. I've added image of TL866 buffer screen after reading process. it looks I cant read and it looks protected. because even if pic is empty, it will return "3FFF" not "0000". Actually I dont need to see code, may be it wont be legal. Just I want to replace the pic with new one. Also this PCB board is very old, I try to find owner of this board. but I cant find him/her.

this is config screen of 18f452 and it looks same problem but there is not code protected from [docs](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39564c.pdf) page 201

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"this PCB board is very old, I try to find owner of this board. but I cant find him/her."_ - The PIC16F676 only has 1k words of ROM, so the program can't be very complex. If you can figure exactly what it is supposed to do you might be able to write your own code for perform the same function.

Comment: Why are you not transplanting the chip onto your new board?

Comment: @transistor i didnt have new board.

Answer (score 2):

They probably have burnt the safety fuse, *exactly* to avoid reading back the software. There isn't a simple mode to recover for it, because that's what is supposed to do.

Another possibility is that the damage has broken the ICSP logic

Comment: I have added config screen of 18f452 and it is also same problem.